# Popover from the click of the content loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have the code

```
jQuery('a[rel=popover]').popover({
  html: true,
  title: '',
  content: function() {
    .....
    .....
  }
}).live('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ......
  ......
});
```

I have the link

```
<a rel="popover" href="#">link</a>
```

My problem is it works fine on click the link that are loaded when the page is loaded. But when the link is loaded via ajax, the popover is not working.

Comment: what is the jquery version you are using ?

Comment: Use event delegation...

Comment: I use jquery 1.8 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure you call popover after the ajax callback function (success)  again for the dynamically added element.. and instead of `live()` use `on()` delegated event

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:.....
    ...
    success:function(data){
        //codes to appene a
       jQuery('a[rel=popover]').popover({
               html: true,
               title: '',
               content: function() {
               .....
               .....
               }
       }); 
    } 
});

jQuery(document).on('click','a[rel=popover]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ......
  ......
});
```